# Encoding video live? (Showing frame which i will overlay on camera while recording video)

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I'm not sure I can really explain this the best way I can, but I'll try my best. 
I want to create custom camera activity, which will capture video from camera, and show some image over that video, and actually encode that image in video. I`m pretty sure I need to use ffmpeg, but, I want to know, is there a way that I can record a video and an image together, and encode it realtime, or do I need to go around, make camera activity, put image over video, as another view, get its coordinates, and then encode it in video using this command:

`ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex overlay output.mp4`

It this command is the only way, how would I add more than one image as overlay?

Comment: Well, you can get the raw pixels from the camera, Modify them anyway you want then encode the file using MediaCodec.

Comment: @szatmary but how fast would it be? It seem like it would be really slow. And how would i do that? Can u write some small example?

Comment: Why would that be slow? If you used an ffmpeg solution, what do you think ffmpeg would do internally that would be different?

Comment: @szatmary Well, i don`t know, i have never worked with raw pixels from camera. But i think that i would do it in Java, which is pretty slower than c when it comes to pixel processing. And ffmpeg is probably optimized, which i`m not sure i can do as the developers of ffmpeg did.